# Dynamics crm filter state drop-down based on country selection

Tags: filtering, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using Microsoft's dynamic crm 2016 online.

I have two drop-downs, one for country and other for states. I want to map states drop-down with country so that once user selects a country, only related states appears as option.
how can this be achieved via crm without using Javascript.

I have tried one approach mentioned [here](http://www.tribridge.com/insights/TribridgeBlog/p2/2011/08/26/how-to-set-up-pre-filtered-lookup-fields-in-crm-2011/) but couldn't able to add data as mentioned in 8th step because in my crm i was not able to see 'Extensions' option mentioned in 8th step.

A step by step solution will be highly appreciable as I am new to Dynamics crm.

Comment: i dont understand why people down vote the question. this isnt a irrelevant question and implementation is tricky. One who have tried will understand the complexity.

Comment: Probably because it didnt fall within these guidelines, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Personally I didn't down-vote, but I can see why others would. Stack Overflow is a programming site, as you can see in the link by James. So what you're asking would be considered off-topic. If you haven't already done so I would consider asking your question on a site like https://community.dynamics.com/crm instead.

Comment: Thanks JamesWood @Conor Gallagher for clearing my thoughts. certainly its look like off topic question but stackoverflow community is more helpful reliable than any other hence we always try to get answer from here, although i put this question here as dynamic crm community response was slow and i didnt find my answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do dependent pick lists (option sets), or dependent lookups?

Lookups, i.e. links to other records. Using the link you provided looks like it would work. In terms of step 8, this

> navigate to Settings → Extensions → Categories. Add all of the new
>   Categories necessary.

Can be read as "navigate to your entity and create your records". Extensions may or may not appear based on which entity you are using and where you have placed it in the site map. The navigation doesn't matter however, the important bit is to just create the records.

Pick lists (option sets), i.e. a static drop down. I believe this is only possible with code. An example can be found at [Sample: Create dependent OptionSets (picklists)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594433(v=crm.7).aspx).

Comment: Thanks James for elaborating it . I was looking for any solution option set/lookup which can give proper UI in form and mainly i can fetch datas via c# plugin. However lookup thing which i mentioned in my question is working now, there was a bug with crm online because of which i was not able to see the last option.